# Making a powershell form button call to a function

Tags: forms, powershell, user-interface, button, onclick

Im trying to build a gui form using powershell, i want to add a button

```
$Button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(35,35)
$Button.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(120,23)
$Button.Text = "Show Dialog Box"
$Form.Controls.Add($Button)
$Button.Add_Click($Button_Click)
```

now i want to create a function called button_click with a few commands, lets say: echo "Hello world"
so i write this:

```
Function Button_Click(){
echo "Hello World"}
```

But clicking on the button wont give me any result, what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Call `$Button.Add_Click($function:Button_Click)` _after_ the function has been defined

Comment: Why write this to a console, if you really are using a GUI?  Just add the text to the form element or add a UI element (textbox, Listbox, etc.) to write to.

Answer (score 3):

You were using Write-Output which will write to the pipeline and in this case will not be displayed because your PowerShell console is locked while the `$form.ShowDialog()` is active.

However you can still do this! `Write-host` is another cmdlet for returning output and it can directly write to the PowerShell host window in real time.  This is one of those rare times when you probably do want to use `Write-Host`.

Then, some small tweaks to make.  Your event handler behavior should generally be defined before adding the `$button` to the `$Form`.

You made a function named `Button_click`, but you add the event handler like it is a variable.  Here's how to do that instead, by making a variable which contains a `{scriptblock}`:

```
$button_click = {write-host "hi Sahar"}
```

And with that done, your code should look like this, and it will work as expected

```
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(35,35)
$Button.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(120,23)
$Button.Text = "Show Dialog Box"
$Button.Add_Click($Button_Click)

$Form.Controls.Add($Button)


 $form.showdialog()
```

[image]

Comment: One could have used --- $button_click = {$env:USERNAME | Out-Host}  --- as wellm thus avoiding the Write-* stuff.

Comment: Remember to vote up and mark as answer if a response helped :)